# ¿Cómo hacer un <div> transparente a los eventos del ratón?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Teniendo este código:

```js
$('.container').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn (){
  console.log('hover dentro');
}

function hoverOut (){
  console.log('hover fuera');
}
```

```css
html, body, .container {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  margin : 0px;
}

.container {
  background : #ffbb00;
}

.element {
  position   : absolute;
  z-index    : 1;
  top        : 0.5em;
  left       : 0.5em;
  width      : 100px;
  height     : 100px;
  background : white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Al pasar el ratón por encima del elemento de clase `.element`, la función `hover` de `jQuery` ejecuta el segundo callback (El puntero ha salido fuera de los límites de el elemento `.container`)

**¿Cómo evitar que detecte el elemento `.element` al hacer `hover`?**

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la propiedad CSS [`pointer-events : none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Cuando esta propiedad está en `none`, indica que este elemento no va a ser parte de los eventos de ratón.

```js
$('.container').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn (){
  console.log('hover dentro');
}

function hoverOut (){
  console.log('hover fuera');
}
```

```css
html, body, .container {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  margin : 0px;
}

.container {
  background : #ffbb00;
}

.element {
  position   : absolute;
  z-index    : 1;
  top        : 0.5em;
  left       : 0.5em;
  width      : 100px;
  height     : 100px;
  background : white;
  pointer-events : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Otra característica no muy clara en el post es que `pointer-events: none` es que también sirve para elementos que están detrás de otros, no solo al frente. Algo que puede ser muy útil en interfaces de usuario complicadas donde hay muchos overlayers.

Comment: Feedback: si fuera mi respuesta, me enfocaria en que hace  `pointer-events: none` y algunos detalles, simplificaria el ejemplo y lo presentaria cerrado pues distrae la vista hacia el ejemplo y se tarda mas tiempo en entender de que se trata la solucion, que por cierto es la unica que anda bien. +1, es util para futuros lectores.

Comment: @rnd Tienes razón. Cuando tenga tiempo investigaré un poco. Recién acabo de descubrir la propiedad `pinter-events`. Si quieres puedes escribir una respuesta, y la marcaré como aceptada. Es por eso que aún no he aceptado la mía. XD Por cierto habría alguna solución para hacer el elemento `.element` clicable y que siga manteniendo el mismo comportamiento con el hover? Saludos! =)